# Can Twilio support a conference with 40+ users?

Tags: twilio

I am planning to use Twilio for an app with [conference functionality](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference).

Conference manager should be able to monitor the conference and manage the users. Twilio seems to support this very easily through its API. But I see a limitation that it allows at max 40 users in a conference, whereas I might want to support upto 70-80 users. Is there a solution to this? can I create 2 conferences and bridge them somehow?

Comment: It would seem that a twilio specific forum might be the best place to find this information

Comment: Contact Twilio support - they should be able to bump up the limit depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Yes, you can create two conferences and bridge them into one another via a Dial command. It is worth noting that you may see some latency between all the links but - from what I've heard - it's manageable.</s>

To correct my earlier statement.. there's not a reliable, useful way to overcome the 40-person limitation. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Official reply from twilio team "It's not currently possible to have a conference with more than 40 participants. Bridging them together isn't possible because each caller can only be connected to one endpoint during a <Dial> meaning you can't <Dial> a conference and a number simultaneously." "

Answer (score 1):

The participant limit for Twilio audio conferencing has changed with the recent announcement of Global and Epic Conference. Global Conference supports up to 250 participants and Epic Conference supports an unlimited number of participants. The other big change is that both of these new products use a global network of media mixers along with Twilio GLL technology to reduce audio latency for international conferences.